# Plumber does not find request body

Tags: r, api, heroku, webhooks, plumber

I am currently writing a webhook on a heroku server and for some reason I am having difficulty obtaining the values stored in the body of the request as it always seems to turn up as `NULL`. My app.R script looks like all those in the guides:

```
#app.R
library(plumber)
library(tidyverse)

port <- Sys.getenv('PORT')

pr <- plumb("plumber.R")

pr$run(
  host = '0.0.0.0',
  port = as.numeric(port)
)
```

My plumber.R file starts like this.

```
library(plumber)
library(tidyverse)
#* Log some information about the incoming request
#* @filter logger
function(req){
  print('LOGGER')
  print( req)
  cat(as.character(Sys.time()), "-",
      req$REQUEST_METHOD, req$PATH_INFO, "-",
      req$HTTP_USER_AGENT, "@", req$REMOTE_ADDR, "\n")
  plumber::forward()
}

#* @filter bodyExists?
function(req, res){
  print( 'BODY FILTER')
  print( req$body)
  if (is.null(req$body)){
    res$status <- 404 
    return(list(error="Body not found"))
  } else {
    plumber::forward()
  }
}
```

Every time it receives a request the console shows out this:
[image]

And stops because there is no body.  I have tried sending it requests from multiple sources where I know a body is being sent with the request but for some reason plumber does not find it when it reaches my api.  I have been following using https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-plumber-app as a template and I don't see what Im doing different from them.

Comment: What types of requests are you sending and how are you sending them? What are you expecting to be in the body? S simple GET request will not contain a body.

Comment: It is supposed to receive POST requests from Fulcrum which is a like a data collection company.  I have never had an issue when Ive built webhooks with them using node.js.  Typically the payload looks something like large JSON object like:                                   
 {
  id: "8faf0917-1987-4ac6-bcc7-4fbf71d191f3",
  type: "record.create",
  owner_id: "00053caf-4b6e-4c86-88b6-64695895dffe",
  data: {...}                                                                                                                            
} @MrFlick

Comment: It's very hard to guess what's going on without a proper reproducible example. Is the JSON data sent with the appropriate content-type header? Does `req$req$body` contain anything?

Comment: `req$req$body` ==  `NULL`.  Is there a way to view the incoming requests?  When I `print(req)` It returns `<environment: 0x561711d66020>` which is useless.  I'm also not entirely sure what that means

Comment: Sorry. that was a typo. I meant `req$bodyRaw`. To see what's inside that environment you can run `ls.str(env=req)`

Comment: I guess Im supposed to be using req$postBody.  That R cheat sheet must have been outdated! Thanks for pointing me to `ls.str(env=req)`! @MrFlick

Answer (score 0):

Was supposed to use `req$postBody` rather than `req$body`

Answer (score 0):

[Plumber](https://github.com/rstudio/plumber) should be able to [parse](https://github.com/rstudio/plumber/blob/935468e8e4748c94780be309b6f4606c7b805aa4/NEWS.md#body-parsing) the body of the post request automatically unless the content type is incorrect or unspecified.

In my case, I had forgotten to specify the content type header of the request (I tested the API using curl from the command line). Once I set it to `-H "Content-Type: application/json"`, plumber was able to parse the body correctly and I could see the payload in `req$body` as well as `req$args`.

If you decide to use `req$postBody`, like the OP did, note that as of [plumber v1.0.0](https://github.com/rstudio/plumber/blob/935468e8e4748c94780be309b6f4606c7b805aa4/NEWS.md#L301) it is recommended to use `req$bodyRaw` rather than `req$postBody`. For more information, see postBody in [the plumber request object](https://www.rplumber.io/articles/routing-and-input.html#the-request-object) as well as plumber [PR#665](https://github.com/rstudio/plumber/pull/665).